# How to store a reference to array instead of literal value, Python Numpy + PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a Python, Pillow and Numpy implementation where I convert a Pillow image into a Numpy array, using the following:

```
bitMap     = Image.open("./big-circle.jpg")
pixelArray = np.array(bitMap)
```

This returns me a nice, clean array. My goal was to create a function which splits each of the pieces of the image into nice equal square segments. This works, but I am left with a variable `squares` which can be referenced similarly to the `pixelArray`, as demonstrated:

```
print(pixelArray[5, 3]) # (255, 255, 255)
print(squares[0][3, 5]) # (255, 255, 255)
```

(The reason for 5/3 vs 3/5 is I store my values as x/y, where numpy extracts them as y/x)

The whole point of this function was to make editing individual squares easier, as it is for a larger parent goal project. Say I wanted to do the following:

```
squares[2][0, 5] = [255, 205, 255]
```

I'd wish for the referenced variable `pixelArray[y, x]` to also change, from this, I'd also imagine it would be able to get the values of the [x, y] from `pixelArray` itself?

In the function, I assign this doing the following:

```
# setting the array full of zeroes
bundled = np.zeros(shape=(x_split, y_split), dtype=object)
...
# inserting, from the pixelArray I wish to reference
bundled[insert_y, insert_x] = pixelArray[store_y, store_x]
...
# finish rest, returning bundled
return bundled
```

This works, but it'd be a much simpler method to be able to reference the pixelArray variable rather than creating some sort of backwards integration function that takes the squares and applies the other metrics to it.

I feel as if I have implemented a very complicated solution to this segmenting problem.

Comment: Just a thought... maybe you need some kind of memory view... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSetchell, I looked into this but it seems that this is a direct re-structuring of the area of the original array. Whereas, I would not know how to reconstruct the array to fit my certain wishes if that makes sense?